# Show the pin info in a uivew

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, mapkit

I'm working with an app, this app use mapkit, now I'm able to display the user current location and when I tap a pin I'm able to display the info but what I want to do is display the info of the pin in the uiview that is on the map view, so when I tap the pin the info should appear in the labels of the uiview instead of appearing of appearing on the pin. Here´s my code and a screenshot.

Hope you can help me

```
    let locations = hardCodedLocationData()

        var annotations = [MKPointAnnotation]()

        for dictionary in locations {

            let lat = CLLocationDegrees(dictionary["latitude"] as! Double)
            let lon = CLLocationDegrees(dictionary["longitude"]as! Double)

            let coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: lat, longitude: lon)
            let name = dictionary["nombre"] as! String
            let adress = dictionary["direccion"] as! String

            let annotation = MKPointAnnotation()
            annotation.coordinate = coordinate
            annotation.title = "\(name)"
            annotation.subtitle = "\(adress)"
            annotations.append(annotation)
        }

        self.mapView.addAnnotations(annotations)
    }

  func hardCodedLocationData() -> [[String : AnyObject]] {
    return[
          ["nombre" : "xxxxxxx" as AnyObject,
                "direccion" : "xxxxxxxx" as AnyObject,
                "latitude" : 19.43017222686738 as AnyObject,
                "longitude" : -99.20263767242432  as AnyObject],
            ["nombre" : "xxxxxxxxxx " as AnyObject,
                "direccion" : "xxxxxxxxxxx" as AnyObject,
                "latitude" : 19.434057416826118 as AnyObject,
                "longitude" : -99.19233798980713  as AnyObject],

            [ "nombre" : "xxxxxxxxxxx" as AnyObject,
                "direccion" : "xxxxxxxxxx" as AnyObject,
                "latitude" : 19.43017222686738 as AnyObject,
                "longitude" : -99.19692993164062  as AnyObject]
            ]


    }
```

[image: This is the mapView]

Answer (score 1):

Sorry I can't comment as don't have the relevant points required yet but I believe the following function should help you:

```
func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, didSelect view: MKAnnotationView) {
    if view is MKPinAnnotationView {
        yourLabel.text = //call up text
    }
}

//or change if view is to
if let views = view as? MKPinAnnotationView {
   //do your updating of labels
}
```